# Get country and Language from locale code

Tags: android, locale, speech-recognition

I have an android method that outputs all the language codes for the speech recognition that are available in the device. The problem is it returns the codes like "en-US", "es-ES", "es-MX"... I would like to know if there is a way to transform these codes into the language's display name (English (USA), Spanish (Spain)...). Thank you for your help.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
    if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE))
    {
        languagePreference =
                results.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE);
    }
    if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES))
    {
        supportedLanguages =
                results.getStringArrayList(
                        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<supportedLanguages.size();i++){
        System.out.println("The language supported is: "+supportedLanguages.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [`Locale.forLanguageTag`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag-java.lang.String-):

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US");
System.out.println(locale.getDisplayName());

// "English (United States)"
```

Comment: There is a method called locale.getDisplayName() that creates the output (English (United States)) by itself without using that last bit of code. Still thank you so much, you solved a problem I had tried to solve for hours in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Build a dictionary from a data source of ISO Language codes:

https://www.andiamo.co.uk/resources/iso-language-codes